# How to insert array of custom objects into mysql database

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, arrays

I'm building an iOS app in which I allow the user to navigate through products and order them. When the user taps order, I want to save his/her username, email, address, date of delivery and of course the array of products he ordered into my mysql database. I need to be able to see the order on my other app which I'm making for businesses.

Saving strings like a username or address is not a problem, but the saving the array of products (represented by custom objects) seems to be going wrong. my database does not return the array it should return when I try to download it on my other app, And i can'f figure out why.

My custom object has the next properties:

itemName, itemCode, itemBarCode, itemCompany, itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemUserRemark, itemCompany, productImageNumber

each variable is a string, and the object represents one item in the shopping cart (represented by orderProducts array) of the user.

I send the order to my web service as follows:

```
NSString *orderToSend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.imagine-app.nl/orderInsert.php?user=%@&orderAdressStreet=%@&orderAdressZip=%@&orderAdressNumber=%@&orderAdressCity=%@&paymentType=%@&orderDate=%@&orderDelivery=%@&orderProducts=%@&company=%@", orderClass.user, orderClass.orderAdressStreet, orderClass.orderAdressZip, orderClass.orderAdressNumber, orderClass.orderAdressCity, orderClass.orderPaymentType, orderClass.orderDate, orderClass.orderDelivery, orderClass.orderProducts, orderClass.company];
        NSString *strURL = [orderToSend stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"connection %@", strURL);
```

and on my web service:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["user"]) && isset($_GET["orderAdressStreet"]) && isset($_GET["orderAdressZip"]) && isset($_GET["orderAdressNumber"]) && isset($_GET["orderAdressCity"]) && isset($_GET["paymentType"]) && isset($_GET["orderDate"]) && isset($_GET["orderDelivery"]) && isset($_GET["orderProducts"])  && isset($_GET["company"]) ){
                $user = $_GET["user"];
                $orderAdressStreet = $_GET["orderAdressStreet"];
                $orderAdressZip = $_GET["orderAdressZip"];
                $orderAdressNumber = $_GET["orderAdressNumber"];
                $orderAdressCity = $_GET["orderAdressCity"];
                $paymentType = $_GET["paymentType"];
                $orderDate = $_GET["orderDate"];
                $orderDelivery = $_GET["orderDelivery"];
                $orderProducts = $_GET["orderProducts"];
                $company = $_GET['company'];

                $result = insertOrder($user, $orderAdressStreet, $orderAdressZip, $orderAdressNumber, $orderAdressCity, $paymentType, $orderDate, $orderDelivery, $orderProducts, $company);
                echo $result;
                }

function makeSqlConnection()
{
$DB_HostName = "xxxxx";
$DB_Name = "xxxxx";
$DB_User = "xxxxx";
$DB_Pass = "xxxxxxx";


    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 

        mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    return $con;
}

function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
{
    mysql_close($con);
}

function insertOrder($user, $orderAdressStreet, $orderAdressZip, $orderAdressNumber, $orderAdressCity, $paymentType, $orderDate, $orderDelivery, $orderProducts, $company)
{
    $con = makeSqlConnection();

    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Orders (user, orderAdressStreet, orderAdressZip, orderAdressNumber, orderAdressCity, paymentType, orderDate, orderDelivery, orderProducts, company) VALUES ('$user', '$orderAdressStreet', '$orderAdressZip', '$orderAdressNumber', '$orderAdressCity', '$paymentType', '$orderDate', '$orderDelivery', '$orderProducts' , '$company');";

    $insertNewItems = mysql_query($sqlInsert,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    disconnectSqlConnection($con);  
}

?>
```

this seems to work since all the objects are inserted in my database. my orderProducts array, containing one ordered products, gets inserted in a cell like this:

(
   ""
)

When I download this order on my business side app, I use this code:

```
on my server side:

    <?php

if (isset($_GET["company"])){
                $company = $_GET["company"];
                $result = getOrders($company);
                echo $result;
        }

function makeSqlConnection()
{
$DB_HostName = "xxxxx";
$DB_Name = "xxxxx";
$DB_User = "xxxxx";
$DB_Pass = "xxxxxxxx";


    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    return $con;
}

function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
{
    mysql_close($con);
}

function getOrders($company)
{
    $con = makeSqlConnection(); 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from items  WHERE company = '$company'");
    $ordersFromDatabase = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $orders['ordersFromDatabase'][] = $row;
    }   
    print json_encode($orders);
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $res;

        disconnectSqlConnection($con);  
    }
    ?>
```

and in the viewDidLoad of my app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Store* myStore = [Store sharedStore];
    NSString *companyID = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: myStore.companyID];

    NSURL *strUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.imagine-app.nl/getOrders.php?company=%@", companyID]];
    NSLog(@"connection: %@", strUrl);
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:strUrl];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonData);
    NSMutableArray *ordersFromDataBbase = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:NULL][@"ordersFromDatabase"];
    NSLog(@"Products Array: %@", ordersFromDataBbase);

}
```

no matter what I do, the array is always null, and I'm nut sure if this is the right way of sending an array of custom objects to mysql.

So my final question, Does anybody know some sample code, a tutorial or just how to send and retrieve arrays of custom objects from Objective-c through php to and from mysql?

Thank you in advance, any held would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try to write the data(jsonData) to a file & check what is the response.It may give you an idea..

Comment: that shouldn't be necessary because my apps perform this kind of actions more, and I never had to write it to a file. normally with this code, my app just gives a nice array of what it received from my database, but now I have the array in it, it doesn't anymore. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

just create a REST server and send data between mobile client and server.

Comment: thank you for your answer!! i'm a beginner in programming and this is my learning project (i set up for myself). can you explain to me how to do this a little bit more in depth?

Comment: REST server gives you possibility sending data between server and mobile client, If you know PHP you can use for example FRAPI (http://getfrapi.com), if you will have REST server installed you can download data from the database using for example JSON or XML. You application will use the URL address with parameters (http://myserver.com/?giveMeTheUserName=123), after that you can read data from server.. you should read about it... it's a very broad subject...

Comment: Thank you, this might work! as soon as I tried and it works i'll accept!